# Restrict/block key presses for input in Python and prevent keyboard key press appearing on next prompt

Tags: python, windows, keyboard, keyboard-events

I'm looking for a way to restrict/block key presses for during input, except for allowing certain key(s).  Also, I don't want restricted/blocked key presses to be registered on screen.

Basic example:

```
input("Enter the letter [p] to proceed: ")
```

When prompted, any key that is not the letter "p", will not appear on screen next to the `input()`.

NOTE: I know about using a `while` loop to check if the correct key was pressed, but that's not what I want to use.

As a workaround, I am using `print()` and [Keyboard](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) python module.

Here is my basic code:

```
import msvcrt
import keyboard

print("Press [p] to proceed: ", end="", flush=True)

while True:
    keyboard.wait("p")
    while msvcrt.kbhit():
        msvcrt.getch()    
    print("p")      # print the letter "p" next to the previous print statement above
    break
```

This works for my needs, but with one annoying issue.  The letter "p" is then flushed to the console, appearing on the next line at the prompt:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

OS: Windows 10
Python version: 3.8.3
Using Windows Terminal (version 1.0.1811.0 as of this post)
PowerShell version: 7.0.3

Answer (score 2):

Use `keyboard.block_key(key)`.

From the [doc](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.block_key):

> **keyboard.block_key(key)**
> Suppresses all key events of the given key, regardless of modifiers.